# Integral of a product of five Bessel functions of order $0$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, special-functions, closed-form, bessel-functions

Does the following integral have a closed form?
$$ \mathcal{J}(2,3,5,7,11) = \int_0^\infty x J_0(x\sqrt{2})J_0(x\sqrt{3})J_0(x\sqrt{5})J_0(x\sqrt{7})J_0(x\sqrt{11})\,dx. $$

I know that some similar integrals do have a closed form
$$ \mathcal{J}(2,3,5) = \frac{1}{\pi \sqrt{6}} \approx 0.12995. $$
$$ \mathcal{J}(2,3,5,7) = \frac{1}{\pi^2 210^{1/4}}K(\tfrac14\sqrt\alpha) \approx 0.110411, \qquad 43-672\alpha+42\alpha^2 = 0, \qquad \alpha\approx 15.9358. $$
(Here $K(k)$ is the complete elliptic integral of the first kind with modulus $k$.)

Numerically, the integral is approximately
$$ 0.061064349908721692\ldots, $$
but I could not find a symbolic value for this constant.

Comment: Just by curiosity: what was the idea behind the calculation of $\mathcal{J}(2,3,5,7)$ ?

Comment: @O.L. I don't know, I saw it [here (problem c)](http://www.siam.org/journals/categories/04-003.php). I'm guessing that products of Bessel functions have nice Mellin transforms (products of gamma functions), so if you integrate a bunch of Bessel functions, you get something like a Meijer G function, which I guess then simplifies.

Comment: I think that the form of the square root coefficients in the arguments of Bessel functions should be crucial for simplification - that's why I am asking. Looking at [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0801.0891v2.pdf) it seems unlikely that even four-argument integral $\mathcal{J}(a,b,c,d)$ can be found explicitly for generic $a,b,c,d$.

Comment: @O.L. [This identity](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.22.E56) looks relevant, so there might be a generic expression for four arguments.

Comment: @O.L. If you know how to derive the four-argument case and can show that the same argument doesn't apply to five arguments, I'd say that's a good partial answer.